# Where is the Mage class declared?

Tags: magento-1.7

In what folder/file is the Mage class declared?

Comment: check here. `your_project_folder/app/Mage.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `app` folder there is this file `Mage.php`. That's what you are looking for.